# Postpone the execution of Javascript wired to a control event in favour of external jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, execution

I have an **ASP.NET Web Form** application developed by another developer.

This developer made extensive use of ASP.NET controls therefore there are many automatically generated **Javascript** functions wired to HTML elements' event.

Now I have been asked to add a functionality: disable the submit button upon first stroke, in order to avoid the users to click several times on the button.

Here is the **jQuery** code that I use http://jsfiddle.net/2hgnZ/80/ and the **HTML DOM** is identical to the one I use:

```
$('#form1').submit(function(e) {
    $(this).find('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    // this is to prevent the actual submit
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

This script in my code does not work and after many attempts I am sure it depends on the **JavaScript** event wired to the onSubmit event of the button.

How can I postpone the execution of this Javascript on favour of the jQuery unobtrusive function?

Answer (score 1):

hmm.  Can you confirm that your event is firing?  I cheked the submit docs, and it is bound rather than live, which is good.

How about wiring to the button, instead?  It would not be perfect, because the enter key doesn't use the button, but if it works that way you'll learn something

Comment: thanks! I don't understand what you mean with 'Can you confirm that your event is firing'. Moreover, wiring it to the button is complex since also the button is automatically generated hence the id is given by asp.net

Comment: Make an alert dialog pop up in your callback, see if it pops up.  For binding to the button, why do you need the id? How about use $('#form1 input[type=submit]').bind('click', function.. Note that the 'click' method defaults to live, so you have to use bind here specifically.

Comment: I already tried the alert does not pop up. It's impossible, I spent an entire day after this..

Comment: It's not impossible, it's probably just really dumb.  Unfortunately I've never used ASP and don't know how or when it binds its events.  Are the elements added in script? In that case you need to be sure their bound by you after they've been added, rather than on DOMready.  Does ASP itself use event binding? In that case you may need to unbind its events.  You may be able to use $(selector).data('events') to see what events area already bound, if jq is used.  What happens if you check the .onclick value?

Comment: the problem is that when you use ASP.NET controls, especially the complex ones such as GridView, Wizard, the engine wires obtrusive JS to HTML elements. And obtrusive JS is executed before unobtrusive JS such as jQuery. Now I am trying to postpone all the obtrusive JS. Let's see what happens

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling e.stopImmediatePropagation(); http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code delays the execution of function amount you want.

```
// delay code for one second
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    window.setTimeout(function() 
    {
        // delayed code goes here
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: thanks, but I need to delay the function wired up to the button (automatically generated by ASP.NET and on which I have no control)

Comment: I don't think you understand the question.  He's looking to stop other people's events, not delay his own.  Your solutions would only make the problem worse.

Comment: @Peter Ehrlich, step1: the button is given an event by ASP generated javascript. step2: you run your own javascript (after), decouple the first event and attach a new one. That was my line of thinking. PS. thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code should help you get the original event and then trigger it after your desired code.

```
$(function(){
    var $button = $('#actionButton'),
    clickEvent = $button.data("events")['click'][0].handler; //saves the original click event handler

    $button.unbind('click'); //and removes it from the button

    //create a new click event.
    $button.click(function(e){
        // doWhatever we need to do
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success: function(){
                $.proxy(clickEvent,$button)(e);//attach the original event to the button
            }
        });
    });
});
```